# Loop over jquery data() object and write values in variables with key as variable name

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-data

Consider a html element with HTML5 data attributes like:

```
<div id="thediv" data-id="somenumber" data-lang="somestring" data-foo="" data-bar="somestring"></div>
```

What I want to do is to loop over the data object and create variables like

```
var key = value;
```

My code looks like this:

```
var itm = $("#thediv");
$.each(itm.data(), function(k,v) {
eval("var " + k + " = '" + v + "';");
});
```

First:

I need to quote the values because if there is an empty one I get an error. But that's ok because I only need the values as strings and I can reparse them if needed in later code sections.

The problem is that I don't get the variables. Let's say I want to see the output I do a

```
console.log("id =" + id);
```

I get the "id is undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is it's defining the variables inside `jQuery.each` block and you are trying to access it outside the block.

So try making variable as global variable using `window.yourvariable` in eval.

**JS:-**

```
var itm = $("#thediv");
$.each(itm.data(), function (k, v) {
    eval("window." + k + " = '" + v + "';");
});
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/nnM9T/)</kbd>

Comment: Just to make sure you avoid any escaping issues: eval("window. " + k + " = v;");

Comment: @BernhardKraus Does this answer your query?

Comment: Thank you. My..."window." was the solution...It works great now. Thanks for editing, Ram.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I should save the data in the "body" tag, using the ".data()" function

```
var itm = $("#thediv");
  $.each(itm.data(), function (k, v) {
  $( "body" ).data( k, v );
});
```

You can retrive the data easly

```
alert( $( "body" ).data( "varName" ) );
```